# Zenity showing Open instead of Save Dialog

Tags: bash, zenity

I have the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

#DATE=$(date +%F-%T)
select=$( echo -e "whole\narea\nwindow" | rofi -dmenu )

FILE_LOCATION=$(zenity --file-selection --save --confirm-overwrite --title="Save As")

if [[ $select == "whole" ]]; then
  # gnome-screenshot -f ~/Pictures/Screenshot-$DATE.png
  gnome-screenshot -f $FILE_LOCATION
elif [[ $select == "area" ]]; then
  gnome-screenshot --area -f $FILE_LOCATION
elif [[ $select == "window" ]]; then
  gnome-screenshot --window -f $FILE_LOCATION
fi
```

When I run the script, the dialog looks like:

[image]

However, it should look like:

[image]

I would also like to select the default file type as `.png`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I am currently using is:

```
#!/bin/bash

select=$( echo -e "whole\narea\nwindow" | rofi -dmenu )

function get_file_location() {

  # Get last save directory location
  if [[ ! -f "/tmp/kdialog_state" ]]; then
    echo $HOME > /tmp/kdialog_state
  fi

  FILE_LOCATION=$(kdialog --getsavefilename "$(cat /tmp/kdialog_state)" "*.png")
  FILE_LOCATION_TEMP=$FILE_LOCATION
}

function copy_image_to_clipboard() {
  xclip -in -selection clipboard -target image/png
}

if [[ $select == "whole" ]]; then
  maim --format=png | copy_image_to_clipboard

elif [[ $select == "area" ]]; then
  maim --format=png --select | copy_image_to_clipboard


elif [[ $select == "window" ]]; then
  maim --format=png --window=$(xdotool getactivewindow) | copy_image_to_clipboard
fi

get_file_location
xclip -selection clipboard -target image/png -out > $FILE_LOCATION

# save last used directory state
echo "${FILE_LOCATION%/*}" > /tmp/kdialog_state
```